# Process variable output not printed

Tags: java

I want a solution for printing value of process variable `p`. How can we print value of `p`? Currently value of `p` is: `java.lang.UNIXProcess@727896`

```
public class shellscript{
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = null;
        String cmd[] = {
            "/bin/bash", 
            "/home/aminul/myscript"
        };
        try { 
            p = r.exec(cmd);
            System.out.println("testing..." + p);
            System.out.println(p);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `toString()` is not overriden for Process class, so you will get `java.lang.UNIXProcess@727896` (default implementation is className@hashCode). What output are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to log the standard output and the exit code of the process, try the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    final Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();

    final String cmd[] = { "/bin/bash", "/home/aminul/myscript" };
    try
    {
        final Process p = r.exec(cmd);

        new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                BufferedReader br = null;
                try
                {
                    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                    String line = br.readLine();
                    while (line != null)
                    {
                        System.out.println(line);
                        line = br.readLine();

                    }

                }
                catch (final Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (br != null)
                        try
                        {
                            br.close();
                        }
                        catch (final IOException ioe)
                        {
                            ioe.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
            };

        }.start();
        p.waitFor();//wait for process to terminate
        System.out.println("Exit code: "+p.exitValue());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Of course, if you want to log the `ErrorStream` as well, you will have to start another thread.

Answer (score 0):

`Process` don't have name attribute. But you can use `pid`.

You can try it in this way

```
Field field=p.getClass().getField("pid"); // use reflection since pid is private
System.out.println(field);
```

But you can't use

```
System.out.println(p)
```

Since `Process` don't have a override `toString()` method